# How do I use transparent PNGs in IE6?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, png, transparency

How do I use transparent PNGs in IE6? I have a corporate app that **must** use IE6 and **must** use use PNGs, but the transparency all comes through as a pale white colour.

Comment: This question was asked and answered on Stack Overflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697682/ie6-png-transparency

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a jQuery [plugin for it here](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/), or the following script also does a good job (just call it in your `<body onload="">`;

```
function fixPNG(){

    var arVersion = navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")
        var version = parseFloat(arVersion[1])

        if ((version >= 5.5) && (version < 7) && (document.body.filters)) 


        {
           for(var i=0; i<document.images.length; i++)
           {
              var img = document.images[i]
              var imgName = img.src.toUpperCase()
              if (imgName.substring(imgName.length-3, imgName.length) == "PNG")
              {
                 var imgID = (img.id) ? "id='" + img.id + "' " : ""
                 var imgClass = (img.className) ? "class='" + img.className + "' " : ""
                 var imgTitle = (img.title) ? "title='" + img.title + "' " : "title='" + img.alt + "' "
                 var imgStyle = "display:inline-block;" + img.style.cssText 
                 if (img.align == "left") imgStyle = "float:left;" + imgStyle
                 if (img.align == "right") imgStyle = "float:right;" + imgStyle
                 if (img.parentElement.href) imgStyle = "cursor:hand;" + imgStyle
                 var strNewHTML = "<span " + imgID + imgClass + imgTitle
                 + " style=\"" + "width:" + img.width + "px; height:" + img.height + "px;" + imgStyle + ";"
                 + "filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader"
                 + "(src=\'" + img.src + "\', sizingMethod='scale');\"></span>" 
                 img.outerHTML = strNewHTML
                 i = i-1
              }
           }
        }

}
```

Comment: +1 jQuery really **can** be used for everything... Who knew.

Answer (score 6):

IE6 supports transparent (but not translucent) PNG's out of the box. The PNG just has to be saved in the PNG8 format. If all you need is a transparent background and not a blending effect you don't need any code. Just save as PNG8.

Comment: That's a very good point.

Comment: I didn't know this - thanks. Neither did our graphic designers, obviously.

Comment: Graphic designers shouldn't have to think about browsers (I wish!).

Answer (score 1):

24 ways has a well-written article on this issue:

http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with GIF-like transparency (in IE6 only), then use PNG8+Alpha (paletted, but with semitransparencies).

It gives full alpha in all other browsers. Does not require slow and finicky DX Filters (on which *all* IE6 PNG24 fixes are based on).

Fireworks and `pngnq`/`pngquant` can save this format (I wrote [Mac GUI](http://pornel.net/imagealpha) for them).

Adobe Photoshop is the only notable software that doesn't support it, but you can export PNG24 and then convert it.